# Inequality in triangle $ABC$ $a=BC$ $b=AC$ $c=AB$

Tags: inequality, triangles, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

Prove that :

$r_{a}^{4}r_{b}^{4}r_{c}^{4}≥9r^{3}p^{9}$

Where :  $p=$ semiperimeter

Actually I don't know if above inequality true or no but my attempt as following :

We known : $r_{a}=\frac{S}{p-a}$, $r_{b}=\frac{S}{p-b}$, $r_{c}=\frac{S}{p-c}$  where $S=$ area

Now by multiple we obtaine :

$r_{a}^{4}r_{b}^{4}r_{c}^{4}=\frac{S^{12}}{((p-a)(p-b)(p-c))^{4}}$

But I don't know to I complete this work ?

Comment: What is $r$?  What does $r_a$ represent?

Comment: For what stands $r$ here?

Comment: @Tomas Houbaze Are you sure that it's true?

Comment: @TomasHoubaze Am I right in thinking $r$ is the inradius while $r_a$ is an excircle radius?

Comment: [Heron's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) might help

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I don't know but Im confused true

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that
$$\frac{S^{12}}{(p-a)^4(p-b)^4(p-c)^4}\geq\frac{9S^3p^9}{p^3}$$ or
$$S^9\geq9p^6(p-a)^4(p-b)^4(p-c)^4$$ or
$$S\geq9 p^2,$$ which is obviously wrong.