# If $a,b,c>0$ and $2(a+b+c)=3$ prove $\sum_{cyc}\frac{9a}{b^2+2(b+1)}≥4$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{9a}{b^2+2(b+1)}≥4$$

With  $a,b,c>0$ and $2(a+b+c)=3$.

First I use AM-GM inequality

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{9a}{b^2+2(b+1)}≥4\left(\frac{abc}{\prod_{cyc}(b^2+2(b+1))^2)}\right)^{1/3}$$
I don't if my idea help me or no and can complete my problem ?

Comment: Even $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{b^2+2(b+1)}\geq\frac{6}{13}$ is true with the same condition.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Which conditions sir ? And how u get it ? Which inequality you use it ?

Comment: The condition is $2(a+b+c)=3$. Yes, I can prove it, but you need before to make something here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288020/ I think I solved your problem there.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg i dont know where the wrong but if you need see no problems ?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}$ is convex for $x\geq 0$, so by Jensen:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b^2+2(b+1)}≥(a+b+c)\frac{1}{\left(\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}+1\right)^2+1}\geq (a+b+c) \frac{1}{\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}+1\right)^2+1}=\frac{6}{13}$$

Last inequality is true because of $ab+bc+ca\leq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}$